# Redefining functions and variables and any other types: Jupyter Lab

Tags: c++, jupyter-lab

The biggest benefit of Jupyter is the fast prototyping it supports.
However, there is one sore sticking point for the [C++ interpreter](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/try.jupyter.org?urlpath=lab).

Suppose I declare a variable:

```
int my_age = 19;
```

Later on, if I change `my_age` and rerun this cell, I get:

```
input_line_25:2:6: error: redefinition of 'my_age'
 int my_age = 20;
     ^
input_line_19:2:6: note: previous definition is here
 int my_age = 19;
     ^
Interpreter Error:
```

It is the same for functions.

```
int sqr(int value)
{
    return value * value;
}
```

Though I understand why it happens, I would wish it simply overwrote the previous value.
What can we do to work around this issue, short of restarting the whole kernal?

Bonus: It would be great if the solution would also account for types, such as classes and structs.

#### Better example:

I have.

```
class Bot
{
    void greet(std::string person)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, " << person << "!";
    }
};
```

and want to change to:

```
class Bot
{
    void greet(std::string person)
    {
        std::cout << "Hi, " << person << "!";
    }
};
```

---

See also:

- [A GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling/issues/91): Maybe I should just wait?

Comment: What is the *real* problem here? Why do you want to redefine the variable, rather than reinitialize/reassign its value? Why do you want to redefine the function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Note that I also want a solution for user-defined types like classes and structs. If I change a class, will I have to rename it? Or restart the kernal? What would you suggest?

Comment: Yes, wait for the issue to be fixed

Comment: @AlanBirtles In the meantime, even partial solutions would be considered. Let's hope for the best!